# Validate with the current session in php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I validate my uid with the current session's uid in this code.
This is the page shown to users after they login to the website. Here they can register for events using their UserId. So how do I validate that?

Code:

```
    $error = array();
if (isset($_POST['uid'], $_POST['eventList']))
{
    if (empty($_POST['uid']))
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a name';
    else
    {
     $query = "INSERT INTO event (Memberid, events) VALUES (?, ?)";
     if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query))
      {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'is', $_POST['uid'], $_POST['eventList']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        echo 'Success';
      }
    }
}
```

This is the List contents

```
Event Name: <select style="width:200px;" name="eventList" tabindex="5">

<form action="page.php" method=POST>
User ID: <input type="text" name="uid" id="uid"><br
<option value="select">Select Event</option>

<optgroup label="Specials">

<option value="Vogue">Vogue</option>

<option value="Raddrock">Raddrock</option>

<option value="Razzmatazz">Razzmatazz</option>

</optgroup>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the content of $list? Can you echo it please?

Comment: I have been using mysql_* till now. It has been working fine. But, I don't know whats wrong with this code.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo just saying he's using `mysqli`, which is not deprecated. However, prepared statements is a good idea. Good article here on that http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Comment: Regardless of the function being used, the code is unsafe because SQL injection is possible. Why is the escaping commented out for $list? Why is it missing for $id?

Comment: What would be solution to my question.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo dw, I liked your comment at first then realized it was mysqli haha. As for the duplicate results, nothing you have shown us can result in that. I'm suspecting the query is being called twice. Can you show us the code for the entire page?

Comment: @Sven First I used escaping thing, it didn't work. So I thought of that function.

Comment: You don't need "escaping thing". You have prepared statements

Comment: "Didn't work" does not describe the error when using escaping. You have to escape, or you will be hacked. ALternatively, use prepared statements.

Comment: @Kevin Pei This is the code for the entire page. I cannot add images, otherwise I would have shown you the image of database results.

Comment: @user3220816 I'm gonna ask you to put `echo "hello world";` right after after you create the `$query`. This will show how many times that code is being called

Comment: What would be the solution to my problem, suppose I used escaping, it still didn't work. It got me duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the database query is executed twice: Once when the page is loaded with the empty form, and then a second time when the form is actually posted with data.

Solution: Only execute the database query after **you escaped the data values** and only after the form was posted.

Comment: My code worked when I used @Justin lurman's code. But, When I try using escaping, I don't get anything in Eventname in my database

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that it is being run twice. Is this in the same file? If so it is running the script when it is first loaded and then again when you submit it. And it doesn't look like you have the query enclosed in anything to keep it from being run twice. You need to check to see if the Post has taken place.